# How to change the color of the scrollbar in map mode

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

In Visual Studio 2017, how can I change the colors of the scrollbar while in map mode?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the colors associated to the following items of the *Tools* → *Options* → *Environment* → *Fonts and Colors* section:

- Overview background
- Overview caret
- Overview collapsed region
- Overview visible

[image: Screenshot]